# kml showing line around equator

Tags: google-maps, kml, google-earth

As of yesterday (20 June 2013) many of my kmls that have worked for the past three years are now drawing as a line around the equator.  This does not affect point features only polylines and polygons.  The behavior has been verified on multiple machines and internet connections.  Again these kmls have been in use and now, without changing anything on my end, are not working.

Has anyone else experienced this and/or have any ideas as to the cause?

Comment: Do you have an example KML or map that exhibits the problem?  Is this on Google Maps, Google Earth or both?

Comment: it is in Goolge Earth.  I'll have an example uploaded in a minute.

Comment: an example can be found here

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5x3DaKThs-HLTdkeHVlanNNR2s/edit

Comment: Can't access that example: You need permission to access this item.

You are signed in as <my email address>, but you don't have permission to access this item. You can request access from the owner or choose a different account.

Comment: geocodezip,

The linked file just opened in google maps (where the error doesn't show) not as a downloadable file.

Comment: However, I worked out the problem.  The program i use to build kml(s) puts a space between coordinates in the array.  Again this did not cause a problem before but it does now in a repeatable way.  Removing the spaces (except after the elevation) fixes this.  I rewrote the program to adjust.

In any case thank you for your time.

Comment: That would be invalid KML (extra spaces within the set of numbers defining a single coordinate),  spaces are used as delimiters between different coordinates, commas between numbers in the single set of numbers that make up a coordinate (either "longitude, latitude" or "longitude,latitude,altitude").